# Vue.JS Passing object to child for use inside slot

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to pass an object that is loaded within DataContainer into a slot, so that the user can customise the view.

```
<data-container silo-id="5">
  <div slot="content"> <!-- I tried  :data="siloData" here but no luck -->
    Your current balance is {{data.balance}}
  </div> 
</data-container>
```

So DataContainer loads the resource via http and sets the value to its 'siloData' property.

DataContainer's template has no content of its own just a placeholder for the slot.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="content"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I try this the text is not interpolated and just remains as {{siloData.balance}} to the browser.

I have tried some examples from Vue.JS site like the todo list, but I must admit utterly confused, maybe because this is not a collection, but just a single (albeit complex) object.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$emit` event

```js
Vue.component('data-container', {
  template: '#data-container',
  data() {
    return {
      siloData: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.siloData = { name: "Silo", balance: 10 } // loading data
    this.$emit('silo-loaded', this.siloData)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <data-container class="card" @silo-loaded="val => data = val">
    <div slot="content">
      Your current balance is {{ data.balance }}
    </div>
  </data-container>
</div>

<template id="data-container">
  <div>
    <slot name="content"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```